dyld[23097]: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject
I am creating an app on Flutter.
Everything works ok before I add a photo_manager: ^3.5.1.
Then I got this error:

dyld[23097]: Symbol not found: OBJC_CLASS$_NSObject
Referenced from: <4DE91EDC-8360-3D98-8708-1A59E6D3BF68> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7D9F2969-506C-490B-89D3-5455EEE99CB5/Runner.app/Runner
Expected in:     <54054A7D-80D5-3095-8B3D-2B33EFEF74D4> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7D9F2969-506C-490B-89D3-5455EEE99CB5/Runner.app/Frameworks/photo_manager.framework/photo_manager
What I've tried:

Changing photo_manager version
Doing all this flutter clean / pod refresh stuff
Adding ${inherited} tag to Library search paths
Changing Deployment target of the project and target to the same version (13.0, 14.0)

dart: ">=3.3.0 <4.0.0"> 
flutter: ">=3.19.2"
Any help appreciate

I had the same error with photo_manager 3.5.0, Xcode 15.0 and iOS simulator 17.2. I upgraded to Xcode 15.3/iOS 17.4 and it now works.

Thanks to haley I solved this problem simply by upgrading my xcode.
